# Upload Image,convert it to zip( client side ) and then upload to server

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

**Upload image file,and convert it to zip on client side and then upload ( converted zip ) file to server.**
There is a js [jsZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) can convert image file to zip on client side,but the question is that how can i upload this converted zip file to server directly.

Comment: this is for input file to zip  https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_data.html#about-blob-since-v300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [jsZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip)

Upload file using HTML

`<form action="/your-action">
  <input type="file" id="mypicid" name="pic">
  <button onclick =" myFunction() "> Upload <button>
</form>`

On upload click convert files to zip

```
  function myFunction(){

/* Make a zip file here */

 var fi = document.getElementById("mypicid");
 var fileInput = fi;
 var files = [];

 // get all selected file

 $.each(fileInput.files, function(i, file) {
    files.push(file);
 });

 //create a zip object

  var zip = new JSZip();

 //add all files to zip 

 function addFileToZip(n) {
     if(n >= files.length) {

//here generate file to zip on client side
        zip.generateAsync({type:"blob", compression:"default"}).then(function(content){

        //generated zip content to file type
            var files = new File([content], "name.zip");

             var formData = new FormData();
             formData.append('fileZip', files);

        //send generated file to server
             $.ajax({
                data: formData,
                url : '/your_path',
                type : 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success : function(response) {
                     alert("success");
                }
            });

        return;
    }
    var file = files[n];                    
    var arrayBuffer;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        arrayBuffer = this.result;
        zip.file(file.name, arrayBuffer);
        addFileToZip(n + 1);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
addFileToZip(0);
}
```

Comment: Something is missing from this code.  It isn't working nor does it collapse correctly.

Comment: @bsguy include https://github.com/Stuk/jszip script, it will work !